# Add new folder with files to github

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Probably one simple question. I pushed my first project to github. I've done it with Eclipse with EGit plugin. I've clicked on a project, chose to push remote and uploaded it to git. There I have created readme file online so the structure looks like this:

```
Git
-- AppFolder
------srcFolder
------libsFolder
------resFolder
------etc etc
-- Readme.md
```

I have one other folder with screenshots of the app which I would like to have outside my app folder. Something like this:

```
Git
-- AppFolder
------srcFolder
------libsFolder
------resFolder
------etc etc
-- Readme.md
-- ScreenshotsFolder
------screenshot1
------screenshot2
------etc etc
```

How can I accomplish that? I don't want to put that folder with screenshots to AppFolder. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locally, just create the ScreenshotsFolder in the same directory level as AppsFolder and README.md.

Then, `git add ScreenshotsFolder` will add the folder and all of its content (really, all content that is not in your .gitignore file if you have one).

Next just `git commit` then `git push remote_repo remote_branch` (ex: `git push origin master`).

If you aren't doing this via the command line, I'm sure the EGit plugin has some option to add the ScreenshotsFolder and do a commit then push...haven't used EGit myself, though.  The steps are the same either way, just a different interface.

Answer (score 0):

Are the files intended to be committed?  If not, you could just [.gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) that directory.

edit: if the files are meant to be committed, why can't you just add and commit them like normal, but in new directory?

Comment: Hm, I don't get it. Why to add it to .gitignore if I would like that folder on guthub? I need that folder with screenshots on github but not inside my AppFolder.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is then.  Just add and commit the files like you would any other way